# button will not change on if else statement when dealing with markers

Tags: android, if-statement, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I have this if else block

```
Marker carLoc; //defined as flied

if(carLoc != null){
        b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img2);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {               

                if(carLoc!=null){
                    carLoc.remove();
                }
                carLoc= map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currLatLng)
                        .title("your car location")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.unnamed)));

                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currLatLng, 17));
            }
        });
    }
```

When I run this code, I can add the marker successfully but when the marker is added, my assumption is that the code is suppose to turn the button image into img1 because the Marker carLoc is no longer null (carLoc != null) but this does not happen. Why does the button not turn into img1 when carLock is no longer null?

Answer (score 0):

you are not change button **BackgroundResource** after **carLoc is not null**

add this line in else part of Button Click event

```
   .
    .
    .

    else{
            b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img2);
            b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {               

                    if(carLoc!=null){
                        carLoc.remove();
                    }
                    carLoc= map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currLatLng)
                            .title("your car location")
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.unnamed)));

                    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currLatLng, 17));
//add this line
    b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img1);
                }
            });
```

Comment: this works but the image wont change back when I remove the marker.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
 Marker carLoc; //defined as flied

 if(carLoc != null){
     b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img1);
 }else{
     b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img2);
 }
 b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
         if(carLoc!=null) {
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }else{
             carLoc= map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currLatLng).title("your car location").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.unnamed)));
             map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currLatLng, 17));
             b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img1);
         }
      }
});
```